# Combine two gm objects while resizing one of them in graphicsMagick for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

```
 var image = gm(someImageUrl)
 .resize(100,100);

 var drawings = gm(200,200,'red')
 .fill('blue')
 .drawRectangle(20,20,40,40);

 // Would be great to have sth like this. 
 drawings.drawImage(image, position)
 // or
 drawings.add(image, position)
 // or
 drawings.draw(image, position)
```

Append is not an option as I would like them to overlap and set precise position to the image

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by resorting to composition options (i.e. the *command()* and *in()* functions on the object that *gm()* returns), which are essentially option flags that you would pass to the shell.

For example:

```
gm()
.command("composite") 
.in("-gravity", "center")
.in(change_image_url)
.in(base_image_url)
.write(out_file, function (e) {
  if (!e) {
    console.log('this worked');
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

However, the caveat is that streams and buffers can't take advantage of them, because the command-line options expect a raw file input. This may work in your case, if you wish to feed in URLs.

Try looking at [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) for actual *drawing* capabilities. You can add image objects, and then use createPngStream to create a stream that Graphics Magick can read, for any last-minute editing/anti-aliased resizing.